# on click not working dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am working on a page with tables. These tables are autofilled. On the first page there are no problems to eliminate an element, because there is a confirmation message to eliminate.

When I go to the next page, and I want to eliminate the click on the "x" to eliminate nothing happens, there is no error, but it doesn't work.

Here is the HTML

```
<form id="{{ $unit->id }}" style="display: inline-block;" method="post" action="{{ url("estates/$estate->uid/units/$unit->uid") }}">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
<a id="deleteUnit-{{ $unit->id }}" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Eliminar" name="eliminar" data-id="{{ $unit->id }}">
<i class="fa fa-times"></i>
              </a>
             </form>
```

And here the JQuery for the confirmation

```
$('[id^="deleteUnit-"]').on("click", function (e) {
            var id = $(this)[0].getAttribute('data-id');

            swal({
                title: '¿Estás seguro?',
                text: "No es posible deshacer esta acción!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
                confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-info btn-fill",
                confirmButtonText: "Si, eliminar",
                cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-danger btn-fill",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: true
            }, function(isConfirm){
                if (isConfirm){
                    document.getElementById(id).submit();
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: How does your "next page" load?  Is it a simple http request for another page, or are you doing some ajax on the current page to load in the new data?  If it's the second thing, I would read [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as it could be that the click handler is not getting added to your ajax-loaded delete buttons.

Comment: @James it is an http request. :)

Comment: `When I go to the next page, and I want to eliminate the click on the "x" to eliminate nothing happens, there is no error, but it doesn't work.`
I don't understand that line. To eliminate what exactly?

Comment: @Touch I click on the <i class="fa fa-times"></i> which has a form of "x"